# Synology DSM 5.0 Routerless Configuration

Tags: routing

I posted this on the Synology forum and received zero feedback...

I was considering eliminating the router from the network configuration by using one of the four ports on a DS1813+ for the internet connection and use the other three on the LAN. Why would you NOT do this??

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly, this would only work if your broadband connection presents as an ethernet so it will not work with ADSL.
2. Secondly, you won't have any dedicated routing control. You would have to take manual, low-level control of the routing. That is likely to get over written every time you get a DSM update.
3. Third, you want a robust firewall as the first thing an incoming connection hits and the last thing outgoing data hits. You don't have much control over the firewall on the Synology if yours is anything like my 412+ - just a simplistic front end to IPTABLES as far as I can tell.
4. Fourth, it isn't designed to do it. You are making it handle all the routing, firewall, intrusion protection, etc. rather than getting it to do what it is designed for.

There is probably more ...

Comment: I agree with 1&2 (with 2 being the strongest argument), but reason 3 of adding manual entries to `iptables` isn't a deterrent.  I don't agree with 4, running VPN and DHCP on DSM are standard practice and the processor can easily handle the additional overhead...

Comment: Well if you are happy will doing it the hard way then 3 isn't a problem. Though I'd still want to test what happens when a big DSM update comes hammering in. We might just have to differ on 4 :) Of course, you've twice the memory than mine, the 412+ quickly runs out of RAM if you run too much. I've got my NAS primarily to be a NAS & then to do the things a router CAN'T, like serving media, dropbox-like sync (over the Internet too!). The router (Billion 7800N) is fine at doing DHCP, Firewall & VPN too if I want (though I probably WOULD use the NAS for that actually as its more configurable).